# FFMPEG Directshow capture windows media player compatible

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

I am using an FFMPEG component in embarcadero C++ Builder to capture video from a Direct show video camera. The capture works fine and gives me good quality mp4 files which I can play back using VLC player or FFMPEG, but the video file is not compatible with windows media player and windows won't give the nice video image when you view a file list with windows explorer.

I have seen suggestions which say you simply need to set the capture format to YUV420P, however if I do this, FFMPEG raises an exception -5 (input / Output error) and the capture device will not open.

Is there any other setting I should be looking at to allow FFMPEG to open the camera and capture the stream so media player will accept it.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? Windows Media Player 11 and lower didn't include an MP4 codec, thus couldn't play MP4. If you install Windows Media Player 12, then you will be able to do so. Alternatively, in Windows Media Player 11, you can download additional codecs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/media-player-11-not-play-video

Comment: Thanks for the input, windows media player on Windows 10 doesn't seem to show a version anywhere, however it does quite happily play other MP4 files. so I assume it is 11.  Whilst you can download other codecs, I would ideally like them to be able to play the mp4 with standard media player.  With the files currently captured by ffmpeg windows plays neither audio nor video, it simply shows a black screen with the correct length for the video displayed at the bottom.  Also windows itself does not show a first frame image, it just shows the default video icon.

Comment: I have media player 12, had to show menu bar to get this, it was hidden by default. This version doesn't seem to have the download codec option anywhere that I can see.

Comment: What's the name of the component you are using in C++ Builder.

Comment: @CSmith I am using the flash AV VCL components. [link](http://www.flashavconverter.com/) this provides a Delphi wrapper for the FFMPEG 4.3.x.x DLLs

Comment: Csmith has told the reason, 
How about you save it with `.avi` extension?
If you do want mp4 file then you need to use ffmpeg to convert it (`.avi` to `.mp4`)

Comment: I really just wanted to know if specific ffmpeg settings would make the file compatible with standard mp4 codec on media player. AvI results in too large a file and I need to be able to playback recording immediately after it completes  so adding another conversion is not an option.